# Oracle using (+) for left outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have this query using outer left self join and it displays what I would expect:

```
SELECT c.date, u.user_id from order_detail_trans c
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_detail_trans u
ON u.trans_id = c.trans_id
AND u.trans_type = 'UPDATE DETAIL'
```

I am joining a table to itself because I want one of my columns (user_id) to be populated only for those rows with trans_type of 'UPDATE DETAIL'... but still need to display rows from this table where this is not the trans type. The above query seems to do the trick. I get records with both trans_types, and those with 'UPDATE DETAIL' as trans_type display user_id

I need this to work with the Oracle (+) syntax, here is what I have going off of this source -- https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/left-and-right-joins-using-the-plus-sign-in-oracle/#performing-outer-joins-using-the-symbol:

```
SELECT c.date, u.user_id from order_detail_trans c, order_detail_trans u
WHERE u.trans_id(+) = c.trans_id
AND u.trans_type = 'UPDATE DETAIL'
```

But this doesn't display rows with trans_type of anything other than 'UPDATE DETAIL'

What would be the correct way of re-writing the first query with (+) syntax to render the same results?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)`  operator and use a explicit `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: What's wrong with just using the `LEFT JOIN`?  If it works with `LEFT JOIN`, why use the `+` method??  It's not recommended.

Comment: Why does every Oracle developer seem to think that using 25 year old syntax improves their queries? Even when presented with empirical evidence to the contrary. Rhetorical question I suppose, but if you guys could like get together and get on the same page as the rest of the SQL world that would be superb. It's like trying to build a house with mud and sticks when we've got concrete, wood and plastic in the year 2018.

Comment: @JacobH: I am offended by "every Oracle developer" ;) - I have been advocating to stop using `(+)` even before Oracle included that recommendation in their manual.

Comment: Wait, so Oracle added the recommendation to use the *incorrect* syntax *after* the standard was changed? No wonder these Oracle devs are all over the place.

Comment: no, why, the recommendation *not* to use it [is in place](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52351). "Oracle recommends that you use the FROM clause OUTER JOIN syntax rather than the Oracle join operator. Outer join queries that use the Oracle join operator (+) are subject to the following rules and restrictions [many restrictions follow]". It reminds me of the comma syntax in MSSQL, towards which we usually show a similar affection.

Comment: @SQLCliff Is this not a place for good code? Oh, sorry you must have realized how hypocritical your response was.

Comment: @M.Doe . . . To elaborate on the other comments, there is no "correct way" to use the `+` syntax, given that even Oracle recommends not using it.  You don't really get a higher authority than the folks who developed and own the database itself.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. The reason I wanted to use the (+) operator is because I'm adding these columns to an existing (and quite large/complex) query which uses (+) and I wanted to stay consistent with what the original programmer had wrote. But from what I'm hearing I should just say "to the hell with that" eh?

Comment: Hey, what's with all this bashing of the (+) syntax? Oracle says this and Oracle recommends that. Did you ever look at the Explain Plan of an outer join query, to see that Oracle **even today** rewrites the ANSI syntax to its proprietary (+) notation? Also, are you aware that some Oracle features **do not work** with ANSI syntax (even for **inner** queries, let alone outer ones), they work **only** with Oracle old style syntax? One of those situations is join materialized views with refresh on commit. Obviously the ANSI syntax should be preferred, but still... Moderation please!

Comment: Yet another Oracle software that *hates* ANSI syntax is Reports Builder. I've had to modify an old report (ver. 9.0.4) and Builder crashed, simply *vanished* from the screen, without even saying "I'm dead!". With the *good, old Oracle syntax* it worked just fine. So ... recommendation is one thing, reality another.

Comment: code looks definitely cleaner with the (+) notation, and I didn't get that memo from Larry btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Need to include the `(+)` Operator on the Condition with the Literal**

The older outer join approach requires that you include the `(+)` operator for the condition on the literal.

Just put your "retro" mental cap on and return back to the 90's. :)

Here is how it should look with this approach:

```
SELECT
    c
.DATE,
 u.user_id
FROM
    order_detail_trans c,
    order_detail_trans u
WHERE
    u.trans_id (+) = c.trans_id
    AND   u.trans_type (+) = 'UPDATE DETAIL'
```

Here is an example with the tables, `emp` and `dept`:

```
SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      d.deptno,
  3      e.job
  4  FROM
  5      dept d
  6      LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e ON d.deptno = e.deptno
  7      and e.job = 'CLERK'
  8  GROUP BY
  9      d.deptno,
 10      e.job
 11  ORDER BY
 12      1,
 13      2;
  DEPTNO JOB     
      10 CLERK   
      20 CLERK   
      30 CLERK   
      40         


SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      d.deptno,
  3      e.job
  4  FROM
  5      dept d,
  6      emp e
  7  WHERE
  8      d.deptno = e.deptno (+)
  9   AND e.job (+) = 'CLERK'
 10  GROUP BY
 11      d.deptno,
 12      e.job;
  DEPTNO JOB     
      20 CLERK   
      30 CLERK   
      10 CLERK   
      40
```

Believe it or not, I believe most Oracle Applications shops just use this older outer join approach.

Comment: What it requires is that if you use (+) with a column from an table/alias then you use it with every column from that table/alias. As clearly stated in the documentation.